# RaspberryPi camera with buildroot

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi2, buildroot

I am working with a RaspberryPi 2 model B and an operating system builded with Buildroot (Linux version 4.0.6-v7). I have the camera module but I can't interface it with my Raspberry. Leds on the camera are always turned off, but the camera is functioning, because I tested it with Raspbian. I tried to install the "rpi firmware" with defaults commands to use the camera, but when I try to take a photo,the system returns this error:

```
# ./raspistill -o picture.jpg
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
mmal: Failed to create camera component mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Camera is not enabled in this build. Try running "sudo raspi-config" and ensure that "camera" has been enabled
```

The command line tools "vcgencmd" return this:

```
# vcgencmd get_camera
supported=0 detected=0
```

So it seems that the camera is really not supported with my system.

Even with "V4L2" userspace driver I have the same problem.

Can anyone help me? Sorry for my bad english!

Thank you very much for any answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite old Q&A but I decided to answer anyway because the question is still relevant and the only given answer is...well pointing to correct direction, but is not how one should fix the issue.

Reason for the error is that using the camera requires extended firmware to be enabled in your RPi build. Yes, it might still work if you'd just download the required files and replaced them yourself like is suggested in haziman's answer. I'm not even sure if that actually was the only way to do it years ago when this was asked. Anyway if not then, at least for few years now it has been possible to configure it at buildroot menu:

```
Target packages --> Hardware handling --> Firmware --> ([x] rpi-firmware) --> Firmware to boot
```

and select

```
(X) extended
```

Comment: Note: start_x=1 in config.txt must not be set when using the extended firmware  as stated in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon the same problem while trying to get up with [Metrological's Buildroot-WPE](https://github.com/Metrological/buildroot-wpe) which I think used the same foundation (Buildroot)

After some google search streaks, I found this: 
https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?pid=292660#p292660 which instructs to put two files - fixup_x.dat and start_x.elf into /boot directory

Let me summarise what I did:

1. Download both files above from 

   `github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/boot/fixup_x.dat?raw=true
   github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/boot/start_x.elf?raw=true`

   into /boot/ partition
2. Put/Uncomment `start_x=1` in /boot/config.txt
3. Reboot
4. Run `raspistill -v` (in my case it immediately show a preview of your camera on-screen)

Addendum: The pi camera board is very sensitive with power surge that i just fried my first board. Had to get another one to get this working.